# Gitlab API get merge request authored by a list of users

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to use Gitlab API to get all MRs opened by set of users. For one user it's this way:

```
curl --location 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/merge_requests?state=all&per_page=500&author_id=123
```

However, I am not sure how to do it for multiple users in single request.

[GitLab API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) do mention the `in` attribute but it's not clear whether it works with `author_id` or not and if yes what's the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the GitLab API documentation, it seems that the `author_id` parameter only accepts a single user ID and cannot take multiple user IDs in a single request.
The `author_id` parameter is used to return merge requests created by the given user ID. The documentation does not suggest that this parameter can take a list of user IDs or that it works with the `in` attribute.

To illustrate that, consider [glab CLI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli) whose [`glab mr list` command](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/main/docs/source/mr/list.md) has a [`ListOptions` structure](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/25f2904f9e947954f96d21bbf6decc856df8202d/commands/mr/list/mr_list.go#L22-26) with only *one* `Author`.

To fetch merge requests for multiple authors, you would likely need to make multiple API requests, one for each author ID. You could then combine these results in your own application.